# React Mui Theme Errror

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, themes

Im triying to make a custom theme with Mui's theme provider, but in the moment i use CreateTheme and put the ThemeProvider, it gives me a few errors.

What i can see, it's a conflict with the native Mui theme, in the app i use some of the Mui elements, like Tooltips, ProgressBars, etc, and i believe that's the problem.

But i dont know how to integrate my custom theme with de Mui's default theme becouse i don't believe the solution is copy and paste the Mui variables to my theme.

Here are some images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have tried to comment the ProgressBars, Tooltips, etc and it works, but i need that haha. I tried to put the ThemeProvider only in a expample

and it works too, becouse there are not Mui elements. But i need to make an full app theme with diferent colors and dark/white mode.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I find the answer my self after a lot of head breaking. The problem wasn't the ThemeProvider or CreateTheme, was the component imports it self. I was importing the LinearProgress, Badge, Tooltips, etc, as "@mui/joy/" and it have to be "@mui/material/".

I hope this help someone.